# Determine Protocol Conformance of Generic (Possibly Protocol) Type

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

Is it possible in Swift to check whether or not a generic type conforms to a protocol, **even if the generic type is a protocol itself**?

```
protocol Parent {}
protocol Child: Parent {}
struct ParentType: Parent {}
struct ChildType: Child {}

func generic<T>(possiblyParent: T?) {
    if T.self is Parent.Type { //Only works for non-protocol types :(
        print("Parameter conforms to Parent.")
    }
}

let one: Parent? = nil
let two: Child? = nil
let three: ParentType? = nil
let four: ChildType? = nil

generic(one) //no, but I wish yes
generic(two) //no, but I wish yes
generic(three) //yes
generic(four) //yes
```

Answer (score 1):

From [The Swift Programming Guide: Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html):

> The metatype of a protocol type—not the concrete type that conforms to
>   the protocol at runtime—is the name of that protocol followed by
>   `.Protocol`. For example, the metatype of the class type `SomeClass` is
>   `SomeClass.Type` and the metatype of the protocol `SomeProtocol` is
>   `SomeProtocol.Protocol`.

Applying this to your problem, you could do:

```
func generic<T>(possiblyParent: T?) {
    guard let p = possiblyParent else { return }

    // You could use an if statement instead of a switch here, if you wanted.
    switch p.dynamicType {
        case is Parent.Type, is Parent.Protocol:
            print("Parameter conforms to Parent.")
        default:
            print("Parameter doesn't conform to Parent")
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let one  : Parent = ParentType()
let two  : Child  = ChildType()
let three: Parent = ChildType()

generic(one)     // Prints: Parameter conforms to Parent.
generic(two)     // Prints: Parameter conforms to Parent.
generic(three)   // Prints: Parameter conforms to Parent.
generic("Hello") // Prints: Parameter doesn't conforms to Parent.
```

Comment: This is close, but a bit different in that it 1. won't work with `nil` and 2. isn't based on what is known at compile time (e.g. an object that happens to conform to `Parent` but was passed in as a superclass type that doesn't conform will be thought of as conforming--desired behavior in some cases, but not here).

Comment: Could you expand a bit on your second problem, perhaps with an example?

Comment: `class Unrelated {} class Secret: Unrelated, Parent {} let example: Unrelated = Secret()`. `example` will incorrectly trigger a conformance statement. (Incorrectly because I'm trying to determine the protocol conformance of the generic type, not of the dynamic type of the parameter.)

Comment: Hummm, it's an interesting problem; you can change what you're switching on to `T.self` (as in your example) which will produce the correct results for your problem in the comment above. However, `generic(two)` evaluates `two` doesn't conform...

Comment: That's exactly the issue. I was hoping there was some other obvious condition involving `.Protocol` or something I was missing, but it's not looking that way...

Answer (score 0):

You might try the standard optional cast:

```
func generic<T>(possiblyParent: T?) {
    if let _ = possiblyParent as? Optional<Parent> {
        print("Parameter conforms to Parent.")
    }
}
```

On Swift 2.0 b3 it seems to work correctly when the optional you pass is not `nil`.

But unfortunately:

```
let someInt: Int? = 3  // no and it is correct
let nilInt: Int? = nil // yes, but it should be no
```

It might be a bug. Anyway if `possiblyParent` is nil, typically there's little more you can do with it.

Thus in case your purpose is to actually use the parameter when it is not empty, you might prefer a generic function like this:

```
func generic<T>(possiblyParent: T?) {
    if let p = possiblyParent, // parameter is not empty
    let parent = p as? Parent  // parameter content conforms to Parent {
        print("parent can be safely used as a Parent.")
    }
}
```

Hope this helps